# Breaking data sets into series for plotting

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a generated a data set of a function $\alpha(\lambda_2,\varepsilon):\mathbb{R}_+ \times (0,1) \mapsto (0,1)$. I used mathematica to generate a list by varying $\lambda_2$ and $\varepsilon$; $\varepsilon$ is very small, and $\lambda$ is in between 0.5 and 1.0.

```
{Nλ1, Nμ1, Nμ2, NCN} = {0., 1., 1., 7060};
Clear[Tableϵ, Tableλ, Tableαϵλ];
Tableϵ = Table[10^-m, {m, 3, 15, 1/3}];
Tableλ = Table[m, {m, 0.5, 1.0, 1/20}];
Tableαϵλ = {};

For[j = 1, j <= Length[Tableλ], j++, {
    lastkϵ = NCN - 1;
    For[i = 1, i <= Length[Tableϵ], i++, {
        With[{Nλ2 = Tableλ[[j]], ϵ = Tableϵ[[i]]}, {
            For[k = lastkϵ, k > Nλ2 NCN, k--, {
                If[ε[Nλ1, Nλ2, Nμ1, Nμ2, k/NCN, NCN] < ϵ && Nλ2 < k/NCN < 2 Nλ2, {
            AppendTo[Tableαϵλ, {ϵ, Nλ2, N[k/NCN]}],
            Break[]
                }];
            }]
        }];
    lastkϵ = k;
    }];
}];
```

Now, I'd like to generate some nice plots. In fact, I wanted to see the curves of $\alpha \approx k/NCN$ as a function of $\varepsilon$ using $\lambda_2$ as series (eventually excluding some to look nicer.

My question is, **how do I break this data set into series that I can filter for some plots**?

Thank you in advance.

```
Δ1[λ1_, λ2_, μ1_, μ2_, c0_ ] :=  1/4 + (μ2/(λ1 + λ2) (c0 μ1 - λ1 - λ2 )/( 2 μ1 - μ2));
Sp1[λ1_, λ2_, μ1_, μ2_, c0_ ] := 1/2 + Sqrt[Δ1[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]]; Sp2[λ1_, λ2_, μ1_, μ2_, c0_ ] := 1/2 - Sqrt[Δ1[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]];
Δ2[λ1_, λ2_, μ1_, μ2_, c0_ ] := (2 λ1 μ1 + 2 λ2 μ1 - λ1 μ2 - λ2 μ2)^2 -     3 (2 λ2 μ1 - λ2 μ2) (-2 λ1 μ1 - 2 λ2 μ1 + λ1 μ2 + λ2 μ2); Δ3[λ1_, λ2_, μ1_, μ2_, c0_ ] :=  2 (2 λ1 μ1 + 2 λ2 μ1 - λ1 μ2 - λ2 μ2)^3 - 9 (2 λ2 μ1 - λ2 μ2) (2 λ1 μ1 + 2 λ2 μ1 - λ1 μ2 - λ2 μ2) (-2 λ1 μ1 - 2 λ2 μ1 + λ1 μ2 + λ2 μ2) + 27 (2 λ2 μ1 - λ2 μ2)^2 (λ1 μ2 + λ2 μ2 - c0 μ1 μ2);  
Sq1[λ1_, λ2_, μ1_, μ2_, c0_ ] := -1/(3 λ2) (λ1 + λ2 + 2 Sqrt[Δ2[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[Sqrt[4 Δ2[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]^3/Δ3[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]^2 - 1]] + (2 π )/3]); 
Sq2[λ1_, λ2_, μ1_, μ2_, c0_ ] := -1/(3 λ2) (λ1 + λ2 + 2 Sqrt[Δ2[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[Sqrt[4 Δ2[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]^3/Δ3[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]^2 - 1]] + (4 π )/3]); 
Sq3[λ1_, λ2_, μ1_, μ2_, c0_ ] := -1/(3 λ2) (λ1 + λ2 + 2 Sqrt[Δ2[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]] Cos[1/3 ArcTan[Sqrt[4 Δ2[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]^3/Δ3[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]^2 - 1]]]);
F[λ1_, λ2_, μ1_, μ2_, c0_, n_] := 1 - (2 λ2 μ1 + λ1 μ2 - c0 μ1 μ2 )/(λ2 (2 μ1 - μ2)) (    1 - Sq3[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]/Sp1[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]  )/(1 - Sq3[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]) Sp1[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]^-n  
ε[λ1_, λ2_, μ1_, μ2_, c0_, CN_] := Chop[(2 λ2 μ1 + λ1 μ2 - c0 μ1 μ2)/(λ2 (2 μ1 - μ2)) (1 - Sq3[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]/Sp1[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0])/(1 - Sq3[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]) Sp1[λ1, λ2, μ1, μ2, c0]^Round[-CN (1 - c0)] ] 
πminus[λ1_, λ2_, μ1_, μ2_, c0_] := (c0 - (λ1 + λ2)/μ1)/(λ2 (2/μ2 - 1/μ1))
```

Comment: By using those symbol names you're looking for trouble! Defne your symbols starting with a lowercase letter

Comment: there is no alpha in your code.. so its not clear what you are asking.  You probably just need do use `Select` to pull out what you want from the list though.

Comment: Below the code, I say $\alpha \approx k / NCN$.

Comment: right so something like ListPlot[{#[[3]],[[1]]}&/@Select[Tableael,#[[2]]==val&]]

Comment: When I run your code `Table\[Alpha]\[Epsilon]\[Lambda]` remains empty. You have a great deal of curly brackets which appear to be not needed. Try editing and follow Dr. belisarius's recommendation of using lower case symbols so as not to conflict with Mathematica symbols.

Comment: the code doesn't work because he hasn't given that *e* function.

Comment: Dear Guilherme, I urge you to read this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/8

Comment: Dear @Verbeia, I usually avoid at it's most using loops structures in Mathematica. But for this very example, where I wanted to calculate $\alpha$ for a given set of parameter, such $\alpha$ was the largest number to satisfy some relation, I really couldn't see other exit. Anyway, thank you for your comment. I'll see if I can reformulate the notebook operations in order to end these loops.

Comment: at least use `Do` instead of `For`.  `Do` can be readily converted to `Table`,  which is probably what your outer loops should be.

Answer (score 2):

```
ListPlot[Select[
  Table[#[[{3, 1}]] & /@ 
    Select[Table\[Alpha]\[Epsilon]\[Lambda], #[[2]] == lam & ],
   {lam, Table\[Lambda]}], Length[#] > 0 &], Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]